# Cannot capture static member with nested lambda

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, lambda

I have a problem with a nested lambda function which cannot see a static class member. Visual Studio 2010 gives me a C2065 ( undeclared identifier ) for reasons I cannot understand.

Here is simple case that highlights my problem:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct foo
{
    void do_some()
    {
        std::vector<int> a;
        std::vector<int> b;

        for_each( a.begin(), a.end(), [&] ( const int& m )
            {
                // works
                auto j = _i + 1;

                for_each( b.begin(), b.end(), [&] ( const int& n )
                    {
                        **// doesn't work**
                        auto k = _i + 1;
                    } );
            } );
    }

    static int _i;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
}
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: This would not be a capture, it would be an ordinary odr-use.  Looks valid, though.  Does it help if you put `foo::_i`?

Comment: Yes that helps! Thanks. what's odr-use?

Comment: "odr-use" is a technical term from the C++ Standard roughly meaning a use of a declaration which requires a definition to exist, and is related to the One Definition Rule.  Only function-local variables need to be captured for a lambda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably a compiler bug (fixed in VC++ 2012). This works:

```
auto k = ::foo::_i + 1;
```