# Overloaded static member function call inside lambda body doesn't compile

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, static-methods, visual-studio-2010

So basically here is the simplified version of my code that doesn't compile:

```
class MyClass
{
    static void foo(X)
    {
        //do something
    }
    
    static void foo(Y)
    {
        //do something
    }
    
    static void bar()
    {
        std::for_each(collection->begin(), collection->end(),
          [&](X& elem)
        {
          foo(elem); //this call generates the error
        });
    }   
};
```

Compiler: MSVC 2010 with SP1 installed
The error message it generates is: error C3861: 'foo': identifier not found

The error doesn't occur if I rename either foo() function, or if I call it outside the lambda.

### Update:

I managed to solve this by explicitly qualifying foo(). The interesting part is that ::MyClass::foo(elem) works but MyClass::foo(elem) does not.

Comment: Hate to fuss, but what's the exact signature of each `foo`? Clearly not `foo(X)` and `foo(Y)`

Comment: is this real code? what's X,Y?

Comment: Do you need `[&]` rather than `[]`?

Comment: Looks like a similar problem to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388520/cannot-capture-static-member-with-nested-lambda

Comment: I stripped down the real code. X and Y are some types. The [&] is irrelevant, I just left it there accidentally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to explicitly qualify `foo`:

```
MyClass::foo(elem);
```

(which might be a required work-around for a MSVC10 bug, GCC accepts your code without qualification)

Comment: Doesn't work, but the error message is changed:
error C2065: '__this' : undeclared identifier
error C2227: left of '->foo' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
error C2232: '->MyClass::foo' : left operand has '' type, use '.'

Comment: I marked this as accepted because it got me closer to the solution, although it was only partially correct.

Comment: @user2849493 Wow, MSVC is even more broken than I thought. :) Glad it helped you to figure out the final solution.